# System.InvalidOperationException: The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component.

Tags: search, administration, enterprise-search, service-application

I am facing a problem on my sharepoint 2013 search service, the problem is as follow:-

1. when i do a search i always get "Nothing here matches your search" even if the entered text match content inside the sites.
2. if i try to do a full search or incremental search it will end after around 10 seconds only.

so i created a new Search service as i though the old search service might be faulty, and the new search service was created successfully, then i click on the new search service then i click on the  "Content sources" , but i got the following exception :-

```
Sorry, something went wrong 
System.InvalidOperationException: The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component '03d855af-c621-45e1-80bd-24850423bb72' in search application 'Search Service Application 4' is in a good state and try again. 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi..ctor(SearchServiceApplication application) 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.get_SearchApi() 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ContentSourceCollection..ctor(Content parent) 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Content.get_ContentSources() 
   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.WebControls.ListContentSourcesControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e) 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() 
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) 
Technical Details 


Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation. 

Correlation ID: 5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52 

Date and Time: 6/1/2015 1:29:16 PM
```

here is the related logs based on the correlation ID :_

```
06/01/2015 13:29:16.66  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Request (GET:http://Tgvstg01:31546/_admin/search/listcontentsources.aspx?appid=0f1fa548%2D6714%2D4064%2D804c%2Db36d6936b853)   5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.67  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Authentication Authorization    agb9s   Medium      Non-OAuth request. IsAuthenticated=True, UserIdentityName=, ClaimsCount=0   5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.67  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Site=/  5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.69  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Server Search        Administration                  dji8    High        SearchApi.cs throws exception:The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component '03d855af-c621-45e1-80bd-24850423bb72' in search application 'Search Service Application 4' is in a good state and try again.  5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.70  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      Application error when access /_admin/search/listcontentsources.aspx, Error=System.InvalidOperationException: The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component '03d855af-c621-45e1-80bd-24850423bb72' in search application 'Search Service Application 4' is in a good state and try again.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi..ctor(SearchServiceApplication application)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.get_SearchApi()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ContentSourceCollection..ctor(Content parent)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Content.get_ContentSources()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Inter... 5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.70* w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      ...nal.UI.WebControls.ListContentSourcesControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)   at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchCentralAdminPageBase.ErrorHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchCentralAdminPageBase.OnError(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.Process...  5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.70* w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         8nca    Medium      ...RequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)   5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.72  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: System.InvalidOperationException: The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component '03d855af-c621-45e1-80bd-24850423bb72' in search application 'Search Service Application 4' is in a good state and try again.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi..ctor(SearchServiceApplication application)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.get_SearchApi()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ContentSourceCollection..ctor(Content parent)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Content.get_ContentSources()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.WebControls.ListContentSourcesContr... 5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.72* w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...ol.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)    at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchCentralAdminPageBase.ErrorHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchCentralAdminPageBase.OnError(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAs...  5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.72* w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Runtime                         tkau    Unexpected  ...yncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)    5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.73  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        Getting Error Message for Exception Microsoft.SharePoint.SPException: System.InvalidOperationException: The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component '03d855af-c621-45e1-80bd-24850423bb72' in search application 'Search Service Application 4' is in a good state and try again.     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchApi..ctor(SearchServiceApplication application)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceApplication.get_SearchApi()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.ContentSourceCollection..ctor(Content parent)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.Content.get_ContentSources()     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI... 5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.73* w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ....WebControls.ListContentSourcesControl.OnLoad(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchCentralAdminPageBase.ErrorHandler(Object sender, EventArgs e)     at Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Internal.UI.SearchCentralAdminPageBase.OnError(EventArgs e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.HandleError(Exception e)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequ...  5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.73* w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         ajlz0   High        ...estMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest()     at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)     at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()     at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)   5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.83  w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x2060  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: (none)     
06/01/2015 13:29:16.86  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Upgrade                         aiaih   High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] desiredVersion: {0}    5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.87  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           General                         aat87   Monitorable     5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.90  w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x2758  SharePoint Portal Server        Runtime                         8gp7    Medium      Topology cache updated. (AppDomain: /LM/W3SVC/1197376329/ROOT-1-130776342738058625)  
06/01/2015 13:29:16.90  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 nasq,1 agb9s,21 dji8,21 8nca,14 tkau,8 ajlz0,150 aat87  5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:16.90  w3wp.exe (0x23E4)                           0x2EA0  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Request (GET:http://Tgvstg01:31546/_admin/search/listcontentsources.aspx?appid=0f1fa548%2D6714%2D4064%2D804c%2Db36d6936b853)). Execution Time=247.133853604299 5c140c9d-4c7f-d003-e007-3a5266e07d52
06/01/2015 13:29:17.24  mssearch.exe (0x2C08)                       0x2C5C  SharePoint Server               Database                        agyjy   Medium      SQL connection time: 129.055089403821 for Data Source=TGVSTG01\SharePoint;Initial Catalog=Search_Service_Application_2_CrawlStoreDB_6136565057f244909b4ad052c84c6bb2;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name="[TSS30a54e77-af39-4dab-8368-7a4e57f7fb05].Net SqlClient Data Provider"    
06/01/2015 13:29:17.24  mssearch.exe (0x2C08)                       0x2D50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin          cd11    Critical    Content Plugin can not be initialized - list of CSS addresses is not set.    
06/01/2015 13:29:17.24  mssearch.exe (0x2C08)                       0x2D50  SharePoint Server Search        Crawler:Content Plugin          du0c    High        Failed to extract required parameter FastConnector:ContentDistributor, hr=0x80070002  [pluginconfig.cpp:81]  search\native\gather\plugins\contentpi\pluginconfig.cpp     
06/01/2015 13:29:17.29  w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x1C84  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                00000   Unexpected  SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory - No cache hosts are present or running in the farm.   31140c9d-7c5d-d003-e007-3d93d547ef4d
06/01/2015 13:29:17.29  w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x1C84  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                ah24w   Unexpected  Unexpected Exception in SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory for usage 'DistributedLogonTokenCache' - Exception 'System.InvalidOperationException: SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory - No cache hosts are present or running in the farm.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()'. 31140c9d-7c5d-d003-e007-3d93d547ef4d
06/01/2015 13:29:17.29  w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x1C84  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                air4g   Monitorable Token Cache: Failed to initialize SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache  Exception: 'System.InvalidOperationException: SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory - No cache hosts are present or running in the farm.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCache..ctor(String name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType containerType, Boolean encryptData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache..ctor(String name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType containerType, Boolean encrptyData, TimeSpan minimumTokenExpirationWindow)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenC... 31140c9d-7c5d-d003-e007-3d93d547ef4d
06/01/2015 13:29:17.29* w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x1C84  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                air4g   Monitorable ...acheInitializer.Init(Object state)'. 31140c9d-7c5d-d003-e007-3d93d547ef4d
06/01/2015 13:29:18.34  w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x28F8  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                00000   Unexpected  SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory - No cache hosts are present or running in the farm.    
06/01/2015 13:29:18.34  w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x28F8  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                ah24w   Unexpected  Unexpected Exception in SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory for usage 'DistributedLogonTokenCache' - Exception 'System.InvalidOperationException: SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory - No cache hosts are present or running in the farm.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()'.  
06/01/2015 13:29:18.34  w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x28F8  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                air4g   Monitorable Token Cache: Failed to initialize SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache  Exception: 'System.InvalidOperationException: SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory - No cache hosts are present or running in the farm.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCache..ctor(String name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType containerType, Boolean encryptData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache..ctor(String name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType containerType, Boolean encrptyData, TimeSpan minimumTokenExpirationWindow)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenC...  
06/01/2015 13:29:18.34* w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x28F8  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                air4g   Monitorable ...acheInitializer.Init(Object state)'.  
06/01/2015 13:29:18.84  w3wp.exe (0x2F34)                           0x27B4  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: (none)     
06/01/2015 13:29:19.14  mssearch.exe (0x2C08)                       0x2AE8  SharePoint Server               Database                        agyjy   Medium      SQL connection time: 124.091679249737 for Data Source=TGVSTG01\SharePoint;Initial Catalog=Search_Service_Application_CrawlStoreDB_d2bf068cf4564147bd01d437b44fcf95;Integrated Security=True;Enlist=False;Pooling=True;Min Pool Size=0;Max Pool Size=100;Connect Timeout=15;Application Name="[TSS0a2b9a82-6d04-4c86-99ea-da551fb10a6d].Net SqlClient Data Provider"  
06/01/2015 13:29:19.14  mssearch.exe (0x2C08)                       0x2EC8  SharePoint Server               Database                        agyjy   Medium      S
```

can anyone adivce on this please? baring in mind that i run the following command :-

```
Get-SPTimerJob job-application-server-admin-service | fl
```

and it showed me that the IsDisabled is set to false .

Comment: How many servers in the farm? Are all the components on the same server?

Comment: yes i have the DB & SP on the same windows 2008 r2 machine ,,

Comment: If you go to the search service application for the one you created, are all the components online ( green check ) ?

Comment: @user19952 yes all are checked

Answer (score 2):

Couple of things to check.

- Make sure Search account have the permission on the search database.
- You can also clear the [config cache on all server](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/b98e0e51-863f-4f61-bcdc-f9acbdf61978/sharepoint-2013-search-error-the-search-application-search-service-application-1-on-server-is?forum=sharepointsearchprevious) in farm( appreantly too much re do work on server.)
- also you can try to change the [app pool for search services application](http://expertsharepoint.blogspot.com/2014/07/the-search-service-is-not-able-to_19.html).

Comment: yes the Search account have DBowner on the DB ,,, i removed the cache but still i am facing exactly the same problems

Comment: what about the changing the app pools?

Comment: ok i changed the application pool, and now all the search instances under "content sources" were set to paused by system .. is this normal ?

Comment: can you adivce on this please?

Comment: i am not sure about the pause, did you try to run those?

Comment: i can not , i try pause/resume but they keep showing "Paused by system" ,,,

Comment: is search service application is running? check this blog, he mentioned two thing resume using the powershell and also naming convention...http://www.sharepointed.com/2013/07/08/paused-by-system/

Comment: seems i will be doing steps without any result ...

Answer (score 1):

Check your Server Status page and validate your Administration Service is running on the same machine as specified in your topology configuration.  It should not be running on servers that are not defined as hosts in your topology configuration.

You can also run

```
Get-SPServiceInstance | where {$_.TypeName -like "*Search*"} | ft typename, status, server
```

This will tell you where each instance is deployed and it's current status.  If any are set to offline (and they should be started), you can run

```
$si = Get-SPServiceInstance <ID>  
$si.provision()
```

That should bring it online.

Be sure to check IIS and make sure all your app pools are running as well.

**Edit**

Check and make sure your services and databases are not in an inconsistent upgrade state.  If they are re-apply the update.

In either case try to re-run PSCONFIG or the Configuration Wizard. This re-installs all the services and configures local security permissions.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I run following command "Get-SPServiceInstance | where {$_.TypeName -like "*Search*"} | ft typename, status, server" and it gave me three rows where all have their status as online

Comment: alos all the application pools are started and running well

Comment: i also noted something weird, that i define the incremental crawl to run each 30 minutes, but seems it will not fire at all , and when i run the incremental crawl manually it will end after 10 seconds only..

Comment: can you adivce on my replied please?

Comment: i remember when i last apply an update , i run the PSCONFIG successfully ,, why i need to run this again ?

Comment: ok i run the configuration wizard successfully, then i created a new search service ,, but when i tried to access the "Content sources" i got the same original exception!,can u adivce please?